# How much battery life can setInterval suck up?

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a JS app that uses setInterval to update itself many times a second. Most of the time it's not doing anything and is not very CPU intensive. I have heard people say that JavaScript timers can eat up battery life on mobiles, but I have not seen any facts or evidence.

Is there any good way to measure the battery drain of my JS app on iOS? Or could someone explain how using setInterval to call a non CPU intensive function would be draining the battery faster?

Comment: What's the nature of the function you're doing many times a second? AJAX? DOM manipulation? What triggers an update? As @Ariel suggests, there's probably a more efficient solution than `setInterval` if you're updating at that frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval wakes up the CPU each time it runs. How many times per second are you talking? If it's more than 10 you should find a different solution, setInterval is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have a specific answer to your question, there are guidelines that you can keep in mind.

Mobile browsers tend not to run javascript code when that page/tab/window isn't active. In iOS for example, code like setInterval will only run while the display is on, while Safari is open, and while the page with the code is active. I believe its similar for Android and WinPhone devices.

Where you have to catch yourself is when developing web apps that are intended to be open for a while. This might be something like a restaurant review site, a game, or something using the geolocation(gps) api. If your web app is intended to be used for long periods of time, then doing constantly running code *will* affect the battery, possibly significantly. You will need to setup a test protocol among different devices and test each one to be sure, as there isn't an easy way to give specific numbers. All web apps are different.